# Get variable sheet name created from show detail from Pivot

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having difficulty grabbing the variable sheet name from my Excel code.

Currently I am extracting the data from a pivot table (like double clicking a pivot table) which produces a new sheet with the raw data.

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("ExportPivot").Range("A5").ShowDetail = true
```

after doing this, a new sheet is created called "SheetX" and of course, the more you run this code the iteration of Sheet will increase.

I tried doing something like

```
set wks = Thisworkbook.Sheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

but the newly created sheet isn't necessarily given a higher number than the worksheets available in the workbook due to deletes.  As a result, a different sheet will be given to WKS and not the one that was just created.

I could potentially get around this by looping through all the sheets and finding the ones with the name "Sheet" and then picking the one with the highest number, but I'm trying to avoid that route.

Thoughts?

Comment: Right after you create a sheet, set a name so you can reference by it later and do not rely on the "Sheet_" that excel creates automatically. After it's created set `ActiveSheet.Name = "SheetNeeded"` or so

Comment: @Sgdva except there's no need for that either. `Set wks = ActiveSheet` right after creating showing the details, then use `wks` wherever you need it, or pass it to whatever procedure needs to work with it. Dereferencing sheets by "tab name" should be a last resort, since it breaks down as soon as the user renames the tab/sheet.